# google maps API v3 div won't fill space properly 100% width + height

Tags: css, google-maps-api-3, size, fluid-layout, variable-width

Here is [my site](http://permanet.cz.cc/index.html). (I have been working on it all morning but there seems to be some issue with my host at the moment so if you cannot connect it should work later).

As you can see the map is too big. I have a sidebar floating on the right of the page with a width of 150px but this is covered up. I also have a footer which I have designed to be 'pushed' to the bottom of the page. Without the map div this works fine and everything is how it should be, but when I create the map div in the remaining space I just can't get it to fill the space properly. If I set width + height to 100% then the sidebar gets covered up and the map extends below my footer by about the height of the footer, which is how it is set now. I have tried setting width and height to 'auto' but this doesn't fix my problem. All it does is constrains the proportions of the div to the min-width and -height that I have set in my code (100x100px). I have already set 'html' and 'body' to 100% and as far as I can tell that is all I should need to do for 'width + height = auto' to work properly.

**CSS**

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
#body {
 height: 100%;
 I have loads of other stuff here but my host isn't working properly at the moment so I can't get to it :S
}
#wrapper    {
 min-width: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 margin: 0  auto -150px;
 position: relative;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

#main {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

#content {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 0;
}

#googleMap {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 min-width: 100px;
 min-height: 100px;
 padding: 0;
 position:absolute;
 top: 86px;
 left: 0;
}

#sidebar    {
 width: 150px;
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 float: right;
 text-align: center;
 background-image: url(../images/sidebar.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-color: #8fa642;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

**HTML** - I have omitted the header etc. for easier reading but this can be obtained using a source-viewer on my site.

```
<div id="main">
 <div id="content">

  <div id="sidebar">
  Hello<br />
  This will be the sidebar!<br />
  It will be pretty plain til I work out the javascript...<br/>
  <img width="60px" height="60px" /><br/>
  <img width="60px" height="60px" />
  </div><!--sidebar-->

  <div id="googleMap" />
 </div><!--content-->

 <div class="push" />

 <div id="footer" class="footer clear">  
  <div class="image_carousel">
  <!-- Elastislide Carousel -->
   <ul id="carousel" class="elastislide-list">
   <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Flagship-Global/135769953251026" target="_blank"><img src="images/slider/flagship.png" height="54px" alt="wwoof" /></a></li>
   <li><a href="http://eebu.earthshipeurope.org/" target="_blank"><img src="images/slider/eebu.png" height="54px" alt="eebu" /></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="images/small/3.jpg" height="54px" alt="image03" /></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="images/small/4.jpg" height="54px" alt="image04" /></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="images/small/5.jpg" height="54px" alt="image05" /></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="images/small/6.jpg" height="54px" alt="image06" /></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="images/small/7.jpg" height="54px" alt="image07" /></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="images/small/8.jpg" height="54px" alt="image08" /></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="images/small/9.jpg" height="54px" alt="image09" /></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="images/small/10.jpg" height="54px" alt="image10" /></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="images/small/11.jpg" height="54px" alt="image11" /></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="images/small/12.jpg" height="54px" alt="image12" /></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="images/small/13.jpg" height="54px" alt="image13" /></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="images/small/14.jpg" height="54px" alt="image14" /></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="images/small/15.jpg" height="54px" alt="image15" /></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="images/small/16.jpg" height="54px" alt="image16" /></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="images/small/17.jpg" height="54px" alt="image17" /></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="images/small/18.jpg" height="54px" alt="image18" /></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="images/small/19.jpg" height="54px" alt="image19" /></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="images/small/20.jpg" height="54px" alt="image20" /></a></li></ul>
   <!-- End Elastislide Carousel-->
   <div class="clear" />
  </div><!--image_carousel-->
  <div id="page_info">
  &#169; Permanet 2013
  </div><!--page info-->
 </div><!--footer-->
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/jquerypp.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.elastislide.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">        
 $( '#carousel' ).elastislide();
 </script>
</div><!--main-->
```

Comment: You are including the Map API twice.Once in main page and once in `js/googleMap.js`

Comment: Oh thanks. I forgot to remove it from the main page. Now I can't see my map at all so I must have gone wrong somewhere, but this still leaves the problem of my overlapping div boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the width of your iframe like this:

```
#googleMap {
  width: 73% !important;
}
```

But what you really need to do it creating two new divs around your google map and around your widget area. Then you will define the width that you want for each of them,
example:

```
#container_googlemap_Map {
  width: 70%;
}

#widget_area {
  width: 30%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but my problem is that my sidebar is fixed width and my footer is fixed height, so if I set the map to less than 100% then when I resize the page it will either overlap or leave a space as the percentage will eventually come out of line with the fixed sizes.

What do you mean by widget area? Is that the sidebar to the right or would that be a container for the sidebar and map together?

Comment: What you need to do is to create two div containers. One around your Iframe and one around your widget area (sidebar).
This will allow you to set up the width of theses divs ( 

#container_iframe {
  width: auto;
}

#widget_area {
  width: 150px;
}

And then, you need to set up the width of your iframe to 100% of the #container_googlemap_Map {
  width: 100%;
}

This will work only if you are displaying the container_iframe and widget_area divs near each other (display inli-block or floating content)

Comment: I have done what you said. Although I am still confused about why you are calling it an iframe. It's just a div box.

It is almost working, except I can only get it to work if the left and right div boxes are set to 90% and 10% respectively. I need the sidebar to be 150px so it is set as #sidebar_container{width:10%; min-width: 150px;) and #googleMap_container{width:90%;}. Both of those encase the two original divs that I had. I have tried setting as #googleMap_container{width: 90%; margin: 0 0 -150px 0;} as well as using display:inline-block; on both of them and it isn't working.

Comment: I have tried to replace margin with padding and neither of them have any effect. At the moment I am just focusing on the width but the height isn't working properly either. That is fixed to the min-height I set for the map, which was 100px.

Comment: I have done this to help you, http://jsfiddle.net/ThPWQ/8/
Have a look and come back to me if you don't get it =)

Comment: Thanks mate. I have been looking at different types of maps and things for the last few days and didn't notice this.. I'll have a crack at it tonight. The only thing I am questioning looking at the code is, with '#googleMap img {}' do I need to replace 'img' with anything to make it work with the maps api or just remove it altogether?